# How to get tag name in sax xml parsing in java

Tags: sax

I am able to get John,B and 12 by `childNodeLst.item(k).getTextContent()`.But how I will get name,grade and age ??
In this xml

`<students>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <grade>B</grade>
        <age>12</age>
    </student>
</students>`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're asking about DOM, not SAX. With DOM, you'd do something like this:

```
private String getChildNodeContent(Element parentNode, String tagName) {
    NodeList children = parentNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    return children.length == 0 ? null : children.item(0).getTextContent();
}
...
Element student = (Element) childNodeList.item(k);
String name = getChildNodeContent(student, "name");
String grade = getChildNodeContent(student, "grade");
String age = getChildNodeContent(student, "age");
```

In SAX, you have to watch startElement() and endElement() go by looking for the start/end tags you care about, and capture characters() events to capture the text.

```
private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

public void startElement(String uri, String lname, String qname, Attributes atts) {
    buffer.setLength(0);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String lname, String qname) {
    String tag = context.pop();
    String contents = buffer.toString();
    // Do something interesting with 'contents' for the given tag.
    buffer.setLength(0);
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int len) {
    buffer.append(ch, start, len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if(preTag!=null){
            String content = new String(ch,start,length);
            if("name".equals(preTag)){
                student.setName(content);
            }else if("age".equals(preTag)){
                student.setAge(Float.parseFloat(content));
            }
        }
    }

Comment: This is unreliable. Many SAX parser implementations will split character data into multiple events, especially when the text contains a character entity reference. For example, "a & b" is encoded as "a &amp; b" and in many cases would be sent as at least three characters() events: "a ", "&", " b".